# Google calendar API - invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked

Tags: bash, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-developers-console

I created a bash script that uses gcalcli to connect to a google calendar and list events. To do that I have enabled APIs for google calendar and generated an OAuth2 token which is basically a .json file containing an access token, a refresh token, expiry date and other information.

My script connects to the calendar every hour, picks up any events and sends me an email. In that script I also monitor the expiry of the token, just to make sure it's up to date and I wont have any connectivity issues.

For one week, that token was always up to date. Every hour I would get the email and checked that the token was current. But every 7 days at 01:00 o'clock in the morning the token expires and I have to generate a new one. The error I'm seeing is the following:

```
oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.
```

This is from the email I get **at 23:00** - This is normal throughout the week, always 1 hour behind

```
token expiry 26/03/2022-22:00:06
```

And this is from the email I get **at 00:00** - The time here doesn't make sense. It's 1 hour and 38 minutes behind.

```
token expiry 26/03/2022-22:22:37
```

And **at 01:00** I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/gcalcli", line 11, in <module>
   load_entry_point('gcalcli==4.3.0', 'console_scripts', 'gcalcli')()
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gcalcli/cli.py", line 152, in main
   gcal.AgendaQuery(start=parsed_args.start, end=parsed_args.end)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gcalcli/gcal.py", line 1238, in AgendaQuery
   return self._display_queried_events(start, end)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gcalcli/gcal.py", line 1182, in _display_queried_events
   event_list = self._search_for_events(start, end, search)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gcalcli/gcal.py", line 1129, in _search_for_events
   events = self._retry_with_backoff(
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gcalcli/gcal.py", line 112, in _retry_with_backoff
   return method.execute()
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
   return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 849, in execute
   resp, content = _retry_request(
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 165, in _retry_request
   resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 186, in new_request
   credentials._refresh(orig_request_method)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 761, in _refresh
   self._do_refresh_request(http)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 819, in _do_refresh_request
   raise HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(error_msg, status=resp.status)
oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.
```

Which shows `invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked`

**What have I tried so far to fix this?**

- On Google I published the project to production, but that had no effect.
- I am not hitting any OAuth rate limits because there are 10,000 grants per day
- I am confirming every hour that the token is refreshed and it is (up until 7 days pass).
- The password of the google account has not changed
- The refresh token is used every hour so it shouldn't expire in a week
- No tokens were revoked, only I have access to this google account

I suspect this is a setting somewhere on google APIs, but I don't know what else to try.

What could be causing the issue here?

Comment: If your app is in production this seems like a bug to me. Consider opening a new [Google Workspace Support Case](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) if you are in possession of a Google Workspace account or file a [new](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=824103) issue inside Issue Tracker.

Answer (score 1):

As I say in the comments, this seems like a bug to me.

From here you have two options:

1. If you have a Google Workspace account, open a new [Google Workspace Support Case](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) to get help from specialists.
2. Open a [new](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=824103) Issue in the Calendar API component and try to reproduce your problem without the use of any external library (in your case [gcalcli](https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli)).

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation [oauth2#expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) You will find that it states

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

While your app is in testing the refresh token is only good for seven days. After that the access to the app will be revoked and the refresh token will automatically expire.

The solution is to set your project into to production on Google developer console under the oauth consent screen.

Comment: as I mentioned, I published the project to production. It is no longer in testing. But the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

To have no limite in the tokens you create for google api, you need to go to gcp and create a service account and use the key provided for it in order to authenticate your requests:

1- Go into your gcp project

2- Enable calendar api

3- Create OAuth and download the json token

4- Create a service Account and create a new json key inside the service account, the key must be a json file, download it as well

5- Go to your calendar you want to access through your api and on the `Share with specific people` add the service account email you previously created

From now on, use that oauth.json and the key.json to authenticate your requests, in that way you will now need to worry about expiration anymore.

Comment: thanks for the information, but the only way gcalcli allows me to authenticate, is by using a clientID and a clientSecret. And it then automatically creates a json file containing entries for an access_token, a client_id, a client_secret, a refresh token, etc.. which then uses for authentication. There's no way I can provide the oauth.json and the key.json for authentication.